# Jpegs Rotated when Attempting to Decode from Byte Array to Display as Silverlight Image

Tags: c#, image, silverlight, jpeg

My DB holds `byte[]` data for different images, `png` and `bmp` extensions work fine but strangely images with `jpeg` extension seem to be rotated 90deg anti-clockwise. I can only assume this is a problem with the encoder and decoder. The `jpegs` are encoded by an iPhone and decoded in a silverlight app using the following code:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bImage, 0, bImage.Length))
{
    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    bitmapImage.SetSource(ms);

    img.Source = bitmapImage;
    tempList.Add(img);
}
```

For `bmps` I use the following:

```
ExtendedImage image = new ExtendedImage();
var bmp = new BmpDecoder();
var png = new PngEncoder();

try
{
    bmp.Decode(image, new MemoryStream(bImage));
}
catch (NotSupportedException)
{
    new MessageWindow("Incorrect image format", DisplayStrings.ErrorDisplay, MessageButtons.OK, MessageImage.Error).Show();
    continue;
}

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
png.Encode(image, ms);

BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.SetSource(new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray()));

img.Source = bi;
tempList.Add(img);
```

Neither option will display the image in the correct orientation. Am I missing a specific jpeg decoder class?

**EDIT**
As it turns out, the iPhone was doing something strange to the byte array. As a result: rotating the image on the iPhone before saving apparently does nothing to the image on the iPhone visibly but uploads the correct orientation of image onto the server. Why this happens is anyone's guess but it is so.

Comment: to ask the obvious: how do you know they are rotated? When an image is taken, sometimes rotation information is placed into the comments section of the jpeg itself and the device/imageviewer will auto-rotate it to correct for orientiation. Perhaps this is what's going on

Comment: I know of the rotation because the iPhone shows the image in the correct orientation but the Silverlight Image shows the incorrect orientation. It could be an auto-rotation problem, do you know how I would be able to check?

Comment: you would have to pull the image onto another device, say a PC and actually open it in a photo editor, eg, MS Paint. This will give you the "true" aspect of the image and tell you if it's an auto-rotation issue. It could well be that Silverlight is displaying it 'correctly' but not looking at the orientation information included with the jpeg

Comment: thanks for your help, it is the byte array that is wrong as they are also showing as rotated from the raw data on my pc - the iPhone must be uploading them strangely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by rotating the image on the iPhone before uploading the byte array to the server. This saves the image with the correct orientation and apparently causes no visible difference to the original image on the iPhone.